# Composite entity compile error in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

```
create table Enroll
(
     Student_ID int primary key not null,
     Subject_Code varchar(10) primary key not null,
     Enroll_Date Date,

     Foreign key(Student_ID) references Student,
     Foreign keh(Subject_Code) references Subject
)
```

My `enroll` table has `Student_ID` and `Subject_Code` as foreign keys and primary in composite table, when I execute this SQL statement, it generates an error, is it anyway to fix this?

Comment: `Foreign keh` spelling is wrong it should be `Foreign key`. Which `RDBMS` yo are using. Also post the error message

Comment: *Foreign keh(Subject_Code)* , correct *key* spelling here

Comment: Keyword "PRIMARY KEY" is not valid as used.. SQLCODE=-637, SQLSTATE=42614, DRIVER=3.68.61

Script: \RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Script2.sql
Database Name: TEST
Authorization Id (Database): db2admin
System/IP Address : DESKTOP-HJIGM59/192.168.0.4
User Id (System) : db2admin

Comment: Try adding parent column `Foreign key(Student_ID)references Student(Student_ID)`. Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: The question has been asked twice already, maybe third time is the charm: what database are you using?  Is it DB2?

Comment: yes its is db2 can u help me to see which part error  or not?i havv

Answer (score 0):

The composite primary key must be declared separately, not as part of its column definitions:

```
create table Enroll
(
     Student_ID int not null,
     Subject_Code varchar(10) not null,
     Enroll_Date Date,

     primary key (Student_ID, Subject_Code),
     Foreign key(Student_ID) references Student,
     Foreign key(Subject_Code) references Subject 
)
```